# Actions called twice, second time with null argument, in controller related to Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, entity-framework-core

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application using Razor and Entity Framework Core. I have defined 2 models, dbsets and tables and I have used Visual Studio to create an "MVC Controller with views, using Entity Framework". It generated a sample code with Index, Create, Edit etc. actions and, after some adjustments, works. A problem I noticed is that Index action not but, for example, Edit action is called twice, first time with good/expected arguments but second time they are null. Inspecting the request.Path on the second, wrong, call, I saw that it looks like

```
[...]/EFController/Edit/site.scss.map
```

Also, the ModelState is invalid because "The value 'site.scss.map' is not valid." I don't understand why this happens, what's the connection with Entity Framework specific code. It is true I have such file:

```
[ProjectRoot]\Client\scss\site.scss
```

The file is mentioned in _Layout.cshtml:

```
<head>
  <environment include="Production">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/@Manifest["scss/site.scss"]!.File" asp-append-version="true" />
    ...
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav
          ...
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="EFController" asp-action="Index">
                    <pre style="text-align:center">Notes</pre>
                </a>
            </li>
etc.
```

It is also mentioned in vite.config.ts:

```
export default defineConfig(async () => {
    const config: UserConfig = {
        build: {
            rollupOptions: {
                input: ['Client/main.ts', "Client/scss/site.scss"],
etc.
```

and in main.ts:

```
import "./scss/site.scss";
etc.
```

I would put some relevant code here but, on one hand, is too much to put everything and, on the other hand, I have no idea what is relevant in order to show some simplified code. The file Edit.cshtml:

```
@model ProgMain.Models.NoteRecord
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <form asp-action="SaveEdit">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="Idx" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Id" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Id" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Id" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        ...
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    ...
<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Comment: There's more to this than Razor pages/.NET and EF.  What's using the .ts files?  Why linking to a ".scss" file instead of a static ".css" file?

Comment: The application is also using Typescript and React.

Comment: You should probably include the React code for the edit page.  Strange that you are using .cshtml files, though.  Doesn't React provide the markup?